# Dropdown menu overlaps other controls

Tags: wpf, menu

In my WPF application I would like to get a dropdown menu under some other elements in the window. When menu is expanded it overlaps other controls. But I need these controls remain over the menu anytime.

I tried to play with ZIndex, but without any success. 
Is it possible somehow to show dropdown menu under other controls?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with a drop-down menu, because by definition it is displayed on a separate window above the current window.

So if you want some control to appear under other controls, you have to use just normal controls like `Grid`, make them invisible at the beginning, and show as soon as you need the "dropdown" to appear (and of course hide afterwards).